# how to anonymously submit information from app

Tags: ios

I am in the preliminary stages of creating an app that will anonymously send information from the user to me.

Because of the nature of the information being submitted, the user may choose to do this without being identified (so email can not be used)

I have previously created an app which email's text fields to a dedicated email address, but i would like to be able to achieve this without the use of the UIMailComposerView.

Has anybody out there had experience in this area? if you could provide some advice on where to get started, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a server running a web service that your app can communicate with.

Comment: @rmaddy - that's the 3rd time today you beat me to a comment by seconds !!!

Comment: @rmaddy could you elaborate on this please? I'm rather new to IOS development.

Comment: @sangony what would you be suggesting?

Comment: rmaddy is right in his suggestion. Passing data to a server would probably be your best choice. Which begs the questions, do you have a server you can use and what kind of software would you be running on it to handle incoming data?

Comment: @sangony i don't have a server - I'm starting completely from scratch. i don't know what i need, how to use it. all i know is that the user will be submitting: the GPS location of the phone, a description of an incident, and a photo or video.

Comment: If you are going to have issues with setting up your server you may want to explore file sharing cloud services  Dropbox, Google Drive has IOS API, there is of course Apple's iCloud, but it is more designed to sharing files of 1 user between platforms than collaboration among many users. There are pros and cons starting with most of them requiring that your users signup with an individual account but anonymity is something you should be able  to program.    Good Luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing you are starting from scratch, there are a lot of options for you to consider.

Hardware: Buying a server is not really relevant to your answer or the right venue for this board and I am sure you don't need help with that.

Software:
PHP - There are A LOT of options out there. The most commonly used one is probably going to be Apache running PHP. There are numerous sites which guide you through the process of setting this up. You can google 'PHP server mac' or something similar for more information. Running PHP is usually free but is also prone to an increased risk of hacking unless you are somewhat of an expert. I only mention this because you stated that your app deals with sensitive information. I am no expert in PHP so you might want to do your own research into this before deciding or post a question regarding this subject.

4D - It's a relational database with it's own scripting language. It also has a large library of web products, has a built in web server, email and FTP capabilities. I've been using 4D for over 15 years and swear by it, so my opinion is somewhat slanted towards this product. It is on the expensive side but offers a free trial. It's data file is encrypted and it has excellent security features. I have written a number of iOS apps which communicate simple text strings, JSON and photos to the database (and back again). Their website is [www.4d.com](http://www.4d.com)

Others - There are many other options aside from the two I mentioned. Google 'database for mac' or something similar for a listing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of information that you would like to retrieve. If you are interested in usage stats of the app, like usage flow, crashes, exceptions, etc. then you should look for a framework dedicated for this. Like google analytics. If you would like user specific information like personal information and such you need to have a server running and use a POST request to it with the information. You can google for RESTful for the last one.

However this last method is a bit delicate since it has to do with user's privacy and your app might be rejected if stated/handled incorrectly.

EDIT:

So, seeing how you want to send anonymous information from the user, this is what you have to do.

Step 1)
Set up a web server, you can either do it physically (have a machine of yours set up as a server) or use a cloud computing server. I recommend the cloud option. Try for example amazon EC2, they have a free tier which you can perfectly use for your purpose, UNLESS you expect to get ALOT of traffic.

Step 2)
Configure the server, its not hard but the instructions depend on the configuration your server is running. If for example you chose to use the amazon cloud servers then they come pre configured. You have to enable them to get RESTful requests (like post). Then save this information somewhere, it could be a mysql database inside the same server for example. Or something external like amazon simpledb which is incredibly easy to use, but its not free.

Step 3) 
On the iphone side you have to send a post request like this:

```
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kServerEndpointAddress];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    NSOperationQueue *someQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                       queue:someQueue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (connectionError)
         {
             NSLog(@"Connection error: %@",connectionError);
         }
         else
         {
             NSString *serverResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSLog(@"Server response: %@",serverResponse);

         }
     }];
```

Notice how the httpbody is an json encoded NSData.

This is just a general guideline. You have to google about the details.

Comment: i think you may have mis-understood my question. Im trying to enable to user to input a description of an incident into a text field, take a photo, and send it to me. i am using emails at the moment, but would like a method which is anonymous.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand it, what you want to do is actually the second option of my answer, I will expand on it on my edit.

Answer (score -2):

If you are just starting it will take you some time to learn web services - you will have no choice but to put up your online resources - web server -

I would suggest instead to access your web server using a URL scheme particularly if they will just comment and very little interaction is required:

In the web server -  enable access to your server via anonymous login and then you can use PHP GET or Post - if you wish to make simple use Get.

Ion your app set up something like this:

```
 NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtrsite.com/comment?u=anonymous&c=comments%20are%20welcome";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Note the URL has limitations in using characters using get so space becomes %20 and other special characters become %xx.   Post will allow you to pass fields but requires more setup on your app ... just look for examples in the web.

The control will also pass on to safari so the user will have to navigate back to your app but it allows you to put up a web page to say - thanks I received your comment.

If you need to interact with the app - you will have no choice but to go with web services (XMLRPC, SOAP or RESTFul).

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it’s all over the place. It contains the kernel of a useful response but not in a way that really explains to the OP what he or she needs to do to get started with server-side web development.

Comment: @bdesham I do not know where you get the nerve to do this, the question is on the IOS coding not on PHP, for all you know he has another guy doing the website for him, if not PHP Get is very basic he needs to be pointed to it and pick it up himself from http://www.w3schools.com.